# How to split cells on different delimiters and make into new columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Say I have the following data in an excel sheet:

```
ID  Text
1   a: khgd
    b - psd
    tx - top
2   rt - wdhg
    c - psty
    rta : vbn
    tx - tcb"
```

[image]

I want to split it with the `:` and the `-`, and make the character(s) to the left of the `:` and the `-` as the column names, and those to the right, the values in the column:

[image]

There may be any number of items in each cell (like, 3 in ID 1 and 4 in ID 2 as shown above). If an item is already a column name, I want to add the corresponding value in the column; otherwise, make a new column and add the value. And if it matters, there are 67000 rows in my excel sheet, each with about 5-6 items per cell.

How do I do this?

Comment: This needs VBA Macro!

Comment: @RajeshS Could you please show how? I'm not an excel user, I just need it for this messy sheet I received. I tried Data -> Text to columns -> Delimited -> Other -> Ctrl+J, and that works for this little sample data I created in the question, but it doesn't do anything in the real dataset.